# Honda Accord 2003 Wont start on cool or cold days

Tags: honda, accord

I have a 2003 Honda Accord 2.4. My car was recently serviced and the spark plugs were replaced and the battery was replaced. I started having problem with the car not starting on cool or cold days. I then returned to my mechanic and got the new battery replaced again. I'm still having the same issue when it's cool or cold. When it doesn't start I wait a little bit and it eventually starts with a little gas. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Any indication on whether the car's having trouble charging the battery?  Is the alternator in good shape?

Comment: Is the engine turning over at all when you try to start on a cold day? If not, do you hear any 'click' noises as you turn the key to try? There's too many possibilities without more information.

Comment: Does it crank, click, or make other noises? does it act the same when you turn all the lights and accessories on? with the headlights on and the key to start, do the lights stay bright or go dim?